# How do data scientists reason under ambiguity?

Tags: probability

I am looking for real-wrold examples of how data scientists build models and make decisions under situations of extreme ambiguity as described by Cassie Kozyrkov [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-does-uncertainty-mean-cac374bb595e):

> A decision under ambiguity involves unknown subjective probabilities
>   that the decision-maker feels powerless to contend with, e.g. any
>   situation where I have no freaking idea and can’t begin to think about
>   what the probabilities might be.
>
> In this framing, the difference between subjective risk and ambiguity
>   has to do with the decision-maker’s skills, perceptions, and feelings
>   about whether they’re qualified to make the assumptions required to
>   assign subjective probabilities to parameters of the situation.

[Various formalisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imprecise_probability) have been developed to reason under ambiguity such as [Dempster-Shafer theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster%E2%80%93Shafer_theory) but I cannot find practical, real-world examples of their usage. I could see such techniques being useful for building COVID-19 models, for example.

Comment: I believe this could be posted on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ as well. It's a better forum for open-ended questions about AI in general